# How to add a static link element as a dropdown list item element in Javascript in Knockout

Tags: javascript, html, css, knockout.js

I am using Knockout JS.

And , the requirement says "In a dropdown , I need to show some data that are fetched from service dynamically.

But when the dropdown is expanded , a link saying "Create New " should also be appended as the last list item in the drop down. "

To get the list items in drop down , I am using ..

```
this.intGroups = ko.observableArray([]);
```

And,

```
    getIntrusionGroupsForSite: function (cb) {
        this.setListValue('/GetGroups', { sId: this.acctId, startIndex: this.pagingInfo.startIndex, maxRecordCount: this.pagingInfo.maxRecordCount }, this.intGroups, cb);
    },

    setListValue: function (api, data, observable, cb) {
        this.postDataRequest(api, data, function (err, result) {
            if (!err && result) {
                observable(result.data);
                if (cb) { cb(); }
            }
        });
    },
```

This code fetches and binds all the "**Group Names**" in the drop down.

But the html looks like:

```
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label">Groups</label>
                        <select size="3" name="intGroup1" id="intGroup1" class="form-control" tabindex="10" data-bind="options: $root.intGroups, optionsText: 'Name', optionsValue: 'Id',optionsCaption: '--Select--',value:$data.IntGroupName"></select>

                        <a href="#" class="ispicon ispicon_plus" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addSchedule" data-bind="click:$parent.addGroup" title="Create New">Create New</a>

                    </div>
```

This `Create New` is now needed as part of the drop down list item only.

How to do that ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate the dropdown options from a Computed Observable - http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html

Get the list of options, and append the extra option at the end:

```
this.intGroups = ko.observableArray([]);
this.dropdownOptions = ko.pureComputed(function() {
    return this.intGroups().concat( {
        Name: 'Create New',
        Id: 'CREATE_NEW_ID'
    } )
}, this);
```

Then in the html, instead of referencing `$root.intGroups`, just use the computed value of `$root.dropdownOptions`